# EF Alter Table with FK error message

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I run in the following error message when I try to run the Seed method.

> System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbUpdateException: An error occurred
>   while updating the entries. See the inner exception for details. --->
>   System.Data.Entity.Core.UpdateException: An error occurred while
>   updating the entries. See the inner exception for details. --->
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: The INSERT statement conflicted
>   with the FOREIGN KEY constraint "FK_dbo.Movies_dbo.Genres_GenreId".
>   The conflict occurred in database
>   "C:\USERS\PATH\SOURCE\REPOS\MVCMOVIE\MVCMOVIE\APP_DATA\MOVIES.MDF",
>   table "dbo.Genres", column 'Id'. The statement has been terminated.

This is my Configuration.cs file

```html
namespace MvcMovie.Migrations
{
    using MvcMovie.Models;
    using System;
    using System.Data.Entity;
    using System.Data.Entity.Migrations;
    using System.Linq;

    internal sealed class Configuration : DbMigrationsConfiguration<MvcMovie.Models.MovieDBContext>
    {
        public Configuration()
        {
            AutomaticMigrationsEnabled = false;
            ContextKey = "MvcMovie.Models.MovieDBContext";
        }

        protected override void Seed(MvcMovie.Models.MovieDBContext context)
        {
            context.Genres.AddOrUpdate(i => i.Title,
                new Genre
                {
                    Title = "Comedy"
                },
                new Genre
                {
                    Title = "Romantic"
                });

            context.Ratings.AddOrUpdate(i => i.Title,
               new Rating
               {
                   Title = "General"
               },
               new MvcMovie.Models.Rating
               {
                   Title = "Parentel guidence"
               });


            context.Movies.AddOrUpdate(i => i.Title,
                new Movie
                {
                    Title = "When Harry Met Sally",
                    ReleaseDate = DateTime.Parse("1989-1-11"),
                    GenreId = 1,
                    RatingId = 1,
                    Price = 7.99M
                },

                 new Movie
                 {
                     Title = "Ghostbusters ",
                     ReleaseDate = DateTime.Parse("1984-3-13"),
                     GenreId = 1,
                     RatingId = 1,
                     Price = 8.99M
                 },

               }
           );

        }
    }
}
```

Rating and Genres are set to be FK in the Movie table. Has anyone had this type of error before?

> > The statement has been terminated.    at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError(SqlException exception,
> >     Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction)    at
> >     System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.OnError(SqlException
> >     exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction)    at
> >     System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(TdsParserStateObject
> >     stateObj, Boolean callerHasConnectionLock, Boolean asyncClose)    at
> >     System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.TryRun(RunBehavior runBehavior,
> >     SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream,
> >     BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject
> >     stateObj, Boolean& dataReady)    at
> >     System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.TryConsumeMetaData()    at
> >     System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.get_MetaData()    at
> >     System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.FinishExecuteReader(SqlDataReader ds,
> >     RunBehavior runBehavior, String resetOptionsString, Boolean
> >     isInternal, Boolean forDescribeParameterEncryption)    at
> >     System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReaderTds(CommandBehavior
> >     cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, Boolean
> >     async, Int32 timeout, Task& task, Boolean asyncWrite, Boolean inRetry,
> >     SqlDataReader ds, Boolean describeParameterEncryptionRequest)    at
> >     System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReader(CommandBehavior
> >     cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, String
> >     method, TaskCompletionSource`1 completion, Int32 timeout, Task& task,
> >     Boolean& usedCache, Boolean asyncWrite, Boolean inRetry)    at
> >     System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReader(CommandBehavior
> >     cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, String
> >     method)    at
> >     System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior
> >     behavior, String method)    at
> >     System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteDbDataReader(CommandBehavior
> >     behavior)    at
> >     System.Data.Common.DbCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior)
> >
> >     at
> >     System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.Interception.DbCommandDispatcher.<Reader>b__c(DbCommand
> >     t, DbCommandInterceptionContext`1 c)    at
> >     System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.Interception.InternalDispatcher`1.Dispatch[TTarget,TInterceptionContext,TResult](TTarget
> >     target, Func`3 operation, TInterceptionContext interceptionContext,
> >     Action`3 executing, Action`3 executed)    at
> >     System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.Interception.DbCommandDispatcher.Reader(DbCommand
> >     command, DbCommandInterceptionContext interceptionContext)    at
> >     System.Data.Entity.Internal.InterceptableDbCommand.ExecuteDbDataReader(CommandBehavior
> >     behavior)    at
> >     System.Data.Common.DbCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior)
> >     at
> >     System.Data.Entity.Core.Mapping.Update.Internal.DynamicUpdateCommand.Execute(Dictionary`2
> >     identifierValues, List`1 generatedValues)    at
> >     System.Data.Entity.Core.Mapping.Update.Internal.UpdateTranslator.Update()
> >     --- End of inner exception stack trace ---    at System.Data.Entity.Core.Mapping.Update.Internal.UpdateTranslator.Update()
> >     at
> >     System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityClient.Internal.EntityAdapter.b__2(UpdateTranslator
> >     ut)    at
> >     System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityClient.Internal.EntityAdapter.Update[T](T
> >     noChangesResult, Func`2 updateFunction)    at
> >     System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityClient.Internal.EntityAdapter.Update()
> >
> >     at
> >     System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectContext.<SaveChangesToStore>b__35()
> >     at
> >     System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectContext.ExecuteInTransaction[T](Func`1
> >     func, IDbExecutionStrategy executionStrategy, Boolean
> >     startLocalTransaction, Boolean releaseConnectionOnSuccess)    at
> >     System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectContext.SaveChangesToStore(SaveOptions
> >     options, IDbExecutionStrategy executionStrategy, Boolean
> >     startLocalTransaction)    at
> >     System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectContext.<>c__DisplayClass2a.b__27()
> >     at
> >     System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.DefaultSqlExecutionStrategy.Execute[TResult](Func`1
> >     operation)    at
> >     System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectContext.SaveChangesInternal(SaveOptions
> >     options, Boolean executeInExistingTransaction)    at
> >     System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectContext.SaveChanges(SaveOptions
> >     options)    at
> >     System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.SaveChanges()    --- End
> >     of inner exception stack trace ---    at
> >     System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.SaveChanges()    at
> >     System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalContext.SaveChanges()    at
> >     System.Data.Entity.DbContext.SaveChanges()    at
> >     System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.SeedDatabase()    at
> >     System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Infrastructure.MigratorLoggingDecorator.SeedDatabase()
> >     at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.Upgrade(IEnumerable`1
> >     pendingMigrations, String targetMigrationId, String lastMigrationId)
> >     at
> >     System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Infrastructure.MigratorLoggingDecorator.Upgrade(IEnumerable`1
> >     pendingMigrations, String targetMigrationId, String lastMigrationId)
> >     at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.UpdateInternal(String
> >     targetMigration)    at
> >     System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.<>c__DisplayClasse.b__d()
> >     at
> >     System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.EnsureDatabaseExists(Action
> >     mustSucceedToKeepDatabase)    at
> >     System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Infrastructure.MigratorBase.EnsureDatabaseExists(Action
> >     mustSucceedToKeepDatabase)    at
> >     System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.Update(String
> >     targetMigration)    at
> >     System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Infrastructure.MigratorBase.Update(String
> >     targetMigration)    at
> >     System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Design.ToolingFacade.UpdateRunner.RunCore()
> >     at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Design.ToolingFacade.BaseRunner.Run()

Comment: first of all you have to make sure that generic table has a row with id 1. Then only you can use that value for genericid in movie.

Comment: I think it can be answered after you add the classes of the entities and MovieDBContext.